# Countdown timer in WidgetKit, SwiftUI

Tags: swift, swiftui, widget, widgetkit

I need to create a widget with a countdown timer, I saw differente resources, but none of them seems to work (even the official apple sample).

Lets say I have an amount of seconds in my main target app, and I access it.

```
class TimerManager: ObservableObject {


   public static let shared: TimerManager = TimerManager()

   @Published var trainingLenght: Int = 60

   func startTraining() {
     trainingTimerMode = .running
     trainingTimer = Timer.scheduledTimer(withTimeInterval: 1.0, repeats: true, block: { timer in
        self.trainingLenght += 1
     })
   }
```

My var `trainingLenght` is now counting down.

How do I display it in my getTimeline method inside my widget?
Once I transformed it as a Date, is it correct to use:

```
Text(entry.date, style: .timer)
```

?

So far even with the official sample https://developer.apple.com/documentation/widgetkit/adding_widgets_to_the_lock_screen_and_watch_faces I'm not able to see the timer counting down.

---

Update:

this is how my getTimeline method looks like:

```
    func getTimeline(in context: Context, completion: @escaping (Timeline<Entry>) -> Void) {
    let date = Date()
    let entries = [SimpleEntry(date: date)]
    let timeline = Timeline(entries: entries, policy: .atEnd)
    completion(timeline)
}
```

Comment: `Timer` will not work in a widget. timeline entries are like screenshots and a widget is like a gif. They don't listen or adapt, more importantly they are rate limited to reloading the timeline only works so many times. Try the "Widget Code Along" they explain all the concepts there.

Comment: @loremipsum I saw different app that contains a countdown timer including the one like in the official sample. But when I build them it doesn't countdown. Isn't the .timer style for this purpose?

Comment: That works with a `Date` the countdown starts from there 1 second after the date, 2 seconds after the date, etc. There is no `Timer` it is just a style `now - you date`. TimelineView lets you create custom views with the same premise but the concept is the same no listening. You can make all your variables a `let` and get the same effect as using an `@Published`, `@State`, etc.

Comment: With all this said, I did see another question on here about `.timer` there may be a bug with the new version but I am not sure, I have not looked into this myself.

Comment: Could you please take a look at this? https://twitter.com/michael_tigas/status/1562703332665602049

I understand your point and I appreciate your answer. My question is, given an amount of seconds, wouldn't be possible to start a timer from now till the number of seconds? (Which can be transformed as a date, like now + number of seconds)

Comment: `Timer` is not possible in a Widget, there is no grey area on the subject. Widgets don't listen. Even in an iOS app expecting a `Timer` to survive for an hour is not a viable approach. They are using something else.

Comment: Yea, I was wondering what is this "something else"

Comment: `Text` with `style` or a `TimelineView` like I said above.

Comment: I mean, I'm not saying that I need to do this with a Timer! I know its not possible, I'm asking how to perform the countdown operation in the getTimeline method given a certain amount of seconds.

Comment: And how do I perform the countdown in the getTimeline method?

Comment: `getTimeline` loads entires... it doesn't count down. You can only call `getTimeline` so many times (think a max of 70). Apple decides when to honor the calls. Look into `TimelineView` start coding making all your variables a `let` it takes some ingenuity but it isn't hard.

Comment: I've updated my question with my getTimeline method. My question is simple, how the getTimeline method know that he has to go from one date to another? Does the ˚style: .timer do all the job then?

Comment: Could you please post a specific implementation for this use case of getTimeline?

Comment: `style: .timer` does all the work, try it out. Look at the "widget code along"

Comment: I've just buildt this sample: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/widgetkit/building_widgets_using_widgetkit_and_swiftui and my widget is not counting down.

Comment: Read through the comments I have already made.

Comment: style: .timer works, but ios16 has a bug. It’s already fixed in ios16.1

Comment: Ah! That might be the answer... I've just build the app in iOS14.5 with an older Xcode and the timer is working fine. I think is a problem with iOS16...

Comment: style: .timer has a major issue in always on state.  It goes from displaying h:mm:ss to displaying h hours mm minutes.  this string is way too long for a widget.  not sure if any way to make it display hh:mm:-- when it drops the seconds in always on.  that's what the native iOS timer does in always on.